# How to properly write to a bash fifo in C?

Tags: c, bash, stream, pipe, fifo

I'm attempting to write an output to a bash fifo so I can pipe it into another program. However, as soon as I run it I get a *segmentation fault*. Any thoughts? (C amateur here)

(**errorout** in this case a global variable and is successfully called elsewhere)

```
void print_log(){
  printf("about to creat file pointer");
  FILE* image_fifo;

  printf("open fifo");
  image_fifo = fopen("image",O_WRONLY);

  if(image_fifo == NULL){
      printf("unable to open fifo");
  }//end if

  else{ 
      printf("writing to fifo");
      int j;
      for(j=0;j<1024;j++){
        fprintf(image_fifo,"%u",errorout[j]);
      }//end for
  }
  fclose(image_fifo);
```

for now, reading it out using this: (isn't python great?)

```
with open("image","r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: Do you get any other output besides the segfault?

Comment: What is a `bash fifo`?  How is that different from a regular fifo?

Comment: `fopen("image",O_WRONLY);` is wrong.  `fopen` takes a char * for its second argument.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: Do you really need a FIFO (i.e. a persistent filesystem object)?  It would be more typical of a C program to create and use an anonymous pipe via `pipe()` and `fork()`.

Comment: If the producer and consumer are 2 distinct applications, then use bash's pipe `|` and in your code write to `stdout` and in python read from `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the segmentation fault is caused by this:

```
 image_fifo = fopen("image",O_WRONLY);
```

This is for calling Linux system style `open()` from `sys/stat.h` (or `fcntl.h`), where the second parameter is an `int` which indicates flags (and `O_WRONLY` is indeed defined to an `int` value in the header file). In C `fopen()` from `stdio.h` you do this with a `char *`, e.g. `fopen("name", "w");`.

To be sure next time include anything the program prints before ending. You might also want to look at valgrind output; it might give you some clues about what's gone wrong.

As for "bash style fifo", I am not sure what you're trying to do, but if you're just trying to write to a file, you're doing it almost correctly. If you're trying to make a pipeline (I've heard someone call them fifo's too, so might be the case), you should look at the [libpipeline](http://libpipeline.nongnu.org/) library and its usage.

Comment: bash fifo, or more appropriately `named pipe`, is created using utilities like `mkfifo` or `mknod`.